# Sort three pointers without using selection sort

Tags: c, function, sorting, pointers, memory-address

I'm new to C and am having a lot of trouble understanding how to utilize pointers in my code. I need to sort the addresses of three user-input integers in ascending order, using a separate sort function. I can't include any sort of selection sort or general-purpose sort, however.

EDIT: When I run the program, it gives me the addresses in descending order for some reason. I need to fix that.

Here's my code thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sortThree(int * a, int * b, int * c);

int main(void)
{
    int x, y, z;
    printf("Please enter three variables: ");
    scanf("%i %i %i",&x,&y,&z);

    void sortThree(int * x, int * y, int * z); 
    printf("%u %u %u",&x, &y, &z);

    return 0;
}

void sortThree(int * a, int * b, int * c)
{
    int min, mid, max;

    if (*a <= *b)
    {
        if (*a <= *c)
        {
            min = *a;
        }
        if (*b <= *c)
        {
            mid = *b;
            max = *c;
        } 
        else
        {
            mid = *c;
            max = *b;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure it's something I'm overlooking or something but my brain just doesn't see it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: so what's the problem? (also, this doesn't sort the addresses, this tries to sort the integers themselves. But it's not complete either. Also, printing pointers using `%u` is undefined behavior - use `%p` and an [explicit] cast to `void *` instead.)

Comment: The problem is that it outputs the addresses in descending order when I run it... I'll do what you suggested. And to sort the addresses instead, would I simply switch all the pointer asterisks with an ampersand?

Comment: `void sortThree(int * x, int * y, int * z);` at inside of main : This is a declaration. It is not the actual function call.

Comment: And are you really want to sort by the address of the pointer? rather than the value of x y z? but  address itself of x, y and z can not be changed.

Comment: Ah, I should have known that. Thanks. And yeah it needs to sort from the lowest location in memory to the highest.

Comment: Although it is possible to change the address of each value is not possible to change the address of the variable itself.

Comment: `int *px=&x, *py=&y, *pz=&z;` do sort px,py,pz.

Comment: Alright I see the flaws in my logic now. Got it up and running correctly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many errors in this code it is hard to comment without re-writing it for you, and I won't. In addition to those mentioned above, you are using `printf()` to show integers by address instead of by value. You can't want to sort the addresses, or you would not have bothered to input any values. Also, why do you switch the format specifier bewteen int and unsigned int? It might not cause an error but it's plain sloppy.

In the sort function, you aren't even changing anything, you are throwing away the results on return. The reason it has given you the addresses in descending order, is because you haven't even sorted them, they are the order they were declared and pushed onto the stack. You are passing the pointers to `printf()` but telling it they are unsigned integers. The actual variable values are ignored.